# Add a prefix to all path with hook_url_outbound_alter and/or hook_url_inbound_alter

Tags: hooks, path-aliases

I'm trying to add a **prefix** to all path aliases, without changing the URL's destinations (*internal path*) of my website.

I'm setting a `$_SESSION` var with `hook_init()` when a visitor arrive on the website. This `$_SESSION` var is determined by the incoming URL of the visitor.

The website is should be accessible by different URL like:

- http://www.mydomain.com/ *(default)*
- http://www.mydomain.com/thisevent
- http://www.mydomain.com/whatevent ...

So if the `$_SESSION` var is "**thisevent**", I'd like to change all default path like this:

- http://www.mydomain.com/some-page into
  http://www.mydomain.com/thisevent/some-page
- http://www.mydomain.com/another-page into
  http://www.mydomain.com/thisevent/another-page ...

I think this could be done with [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) and/or [`hook_url_inbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) but I can find any clear examples to implement my goal. 
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851610/additionnal-path-prefix-on-drupal-7/23273482#23273482) but the author didn't post his solution.

Any help appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like an odd approach, what is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to add a prefix to my paths without changing the internal path and finally having access to the site with different URL (prefixed or not). And hello homonym, nice to meet you :-)

Comment: Can you not just use pathauto and URL aliases?

Comment: I'm using it to set the default aliases. But then I want to add a prefix to this already set aliases when a user comes with a different url then the default one. Those URL are created by a certain content type.

Comment: This gets really hairy really quickly.  I did it recently, and will try to summarize the nuances.

Comment: @MPD I'm looking forward for your answer. Hope you won't get to hairy for that ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it but not without the help of a sympathetic module: [PURL](https://drupal.org/project/purl).

And here's my final solution:

1. Create a custom module
2. In the `mymodule.module` file create 3 functions:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_purl_provider
    */
   function mymodule_purl_provider() {
     return array(
       'mymodule_provider' => array(
         'name' => t('My module provider'),
         'description' => t('Sets a prefix for URL.'),
         'callback' => '_mymodule_prefix',//I didn't really use this callback and I don't really know how to :-)
         'example' => 'my-prefix',//anything you want. only for UI I think
       ),
     );
   }

   function mymodule_purl_modifiers() {

     $mymodule_events = _get_all_events();//custom function to get some data

     foreach ($mymodule_events as $kid => $e) {
       $modtab['mymodule_provider'][] = array('value' => $e['alias'], 'id' => $e['nid']);//this array must be structured like this!
     }
     return $modtab;
   }


   function _mymodule_prefix(){
     $event = _get_one_event();//custom function

     if ($event) return true;
   }
   ```

then you can go in `/admin/config/search/purl` to configure PURL with your data you've just created with mymodule.

1. In `/admin/config/search/purl/types` you select the type you need (I checked only "Path")
2. In `/admin/config/search/purl/list` you should see your modifiers you've created with mymodule.
3. And in `/admin/config/search/purl` you can select witch type you use for your provider

I am a bit sad because I didn't manage to use the 2 hooks (like purl does :-) but the good news is that "it works"

Cheers.